# Is it possible for me to develop a lawnmowing technology incorporating Object Avoidance

Tags: patent-infringement

I am currently trying to create a lawn mowing robot which also uses Object Detection. Does the following patent prohibit me from doing this?
http://www.freepatentsonline.com/9563204.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claims seem pretty broad but patents do not cover a result, rather a particular manner of achieving a result. You might study this patent, and many others in the same field and see a good way to address the problem that does not fall under anyone's claims. You can start by looking at earlier patents cited in this patent and subsequent patents that cite this patent as well as doing a more comprehensive search.

Another search element could be to look at other patent by the same inventor. Put inventor:(Mikael Willgert) into google patents to see a few titles that seem relevant like - Boundary definition system for a robotic vehicle - US9497901B2

You not only need to avoid patents specific to automated lawnmowers but patents that might be broader. The particular way you might combine radar and lidar data (to make up an example), might be patented outside the application area you are interested in. An extreme example is that there are patents are tire tread patterns.

Comment: Hi George, thanks for your response, I will have a look at that, thank you for clarifying that patents do not cover results, I will try and find a way on how to work to the goal without infringing on copyright and look for other possible infringements. Cheers

Comment: @IanRonk  First claim has the phrase: "receiving information indicative of an encounter between a robotic vehicle and an object responsive to communication received from a sensor" so it seems it is limited to the case where the object you are trying to avoid is responsive to a signal from the robot. Not, for instance, a person.

Comment: @EricShain, it also says that it comes from a sensor, so would that mean that for example using object recognition using a camera as input is something that wouldn't infringe the patent?

Comment: It might be arguable as to a camera being a sensor except - "9. The method of claim 1, wherein the sensor comprises a camera, a radar device, a laser scanner, or an ultrasonic sensor."  Your search will require a high degree of attention to detail.

Comment: @EricShain - the "responsive" phrase seems a little muddled to me in the claim. As you quoted it sounds like the object responds to the sensor. This seems backwards. sensors sense, they do not emit so how the object responds to something the sensor does is not clear. It may be that the "responsiveness"  means detectable by the sensor, i.e. light reflects from the object.

Comment: Okay, I will have a look at it then, that would be a direct exclusion of that possibility if cameras are out of question

Comment: The independent claims have many elements. To infringe you need to have those elements and they need to have the relationships to each other defined in the claim. One element of the claim ( a sensor that can be a camera) being the same as one element of your invention (a camera) does not, itself, stop you. There are other elements you can try to understand and see if your ideas require those elements or not.